# Destructor and delete

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a C++ class, `MyClass`. It contains a constructor, destructor and an int pointer `private: int *MyPtr;`.

Somewhere, I allocate dynamically a `MyClass` Object:

```
MyClass *my = new MyClass(); //...
```

Then I call `delete my;`

Should `MyClass` have a destructor which uses something like `delete MyPtr`? Or is that MyPtr  destroyed when I call `delete my`?

Comment: `delete` what you `new`. Anyway, just use a smart pointer instead if you need DMA.

Comment: Is `MyPtr` allocated in the constructor with `new`? If so then you need to manually call `delete` (and obey the **rule of three**). Otherwise no as your object does not own the pointer held by `MyPtr`. The call to delete should only be done by the owner of the pointer. You have not made clear the ownership semantics of your class so the answer is debatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Or is that MyPtr destroyed when I call delete my?`

No, when you call `delete my;` this will call the destructor of `MyClass` and unless you explicitly delete MyPtr in the destructor you will have a memory leak.

`Should MyClass have a destructor which uses something like delete MyPtr?`

Always delete dynamically allocated memory in your destructor - that is what destructors are meant for.

Comment: So, "delete my" instruction will deallocate the involved memory taken by my object instance, but not its fields such as MyPtr? Isn't it?

Comment: Only the **pointer** MyPtr  is a field in the class, not the memory it is pointing to. So when you destroy the class, the memory used for the pointer will be released, but not the memory **pointed to** by the pointer. Freeing that memory is your responsibility.

Comment: Assuming the object owns the pointer. That point is not made clear by the question.

Comment: @LokiAstari true. I thought for a while if I should add this to my answer but thought it will be more confusing than helping.

Comment: @PeterWood I thought my first sentence made that clear. Do you think I should add it explicitly?

Answer (score 5):

If you allocated MyPtr insid MyClass constructor then it's your responsibility to delete it. Otherwise if you delete an unallocated memory it causes undefined behavior.

An idiomatic way is to use smart pointer inside class if you need to dynamic allocate memory and delete it, smart pointer will look after memory deallocation for you.

probaby worth a read: [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
delete my
```

you don't deallocate the data of that class (unless you specify it in the destructor), so this will lead to a memory leak.